# Не могу открыть pdf файл в папке нижнего уровня

Tags: java, android, uri

В приложении я пытаюсь открыть `pdf` файлы, когда файл лежит на верхнем уровне, то никаких проблем не возникает, но когда файл лежит в папке нижнего уровня, то он не открывается, в строке `if (pdfFile.exists())` код не отрабатывает, не могу понять в чем проблема.

Код привожу ниже:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPressMe);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("file/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 100500);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.i("File was choosed", "File was choosed");
            if (RESULT_OK == resultCode && 100500 == requestCode) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.i("URI", "URI " + uri);
                invokeMethod(uri);
            }
        }

        private void invokeMethod(Uri uri) {
            File pdfFile = new File(uri.getPath());
            Log.i("URI get Path", uri.getPath());

            try {
               if (pdfFile.exists()) {
                   Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   objIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                   objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                   startActivity(objIntent);
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File NotFound",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Viewer Application Found", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: что значит `код не отрабатывает`? Не выполняется строка? Не выполняется условие?

Comment: @metalurgus Не выполняется условие

Comment: возможно нет разрешений на чтение этого фалла?

Comment: А вне вашей программы данная pdf-ка открывается?

Comment: Добавила в Манифест WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,  READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE теперь открываются pdf  файлы с папок любого уровня, если я захожу через специальный файл менеджер (Asro file manager), но когда я хочу открыть файлы через дефолтный файл менеджер, они являются неактивными для выбора.